# Access problems to a local folder via a network share

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a Windows service, running using the login `localhost\administrator`.  This service is meant to invoke another executable (`MyProcess.exe`), which is supposed to write some stuff to a log file.  The service uses `Process.Start()` to create the process, like so:

```
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = processFileName;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = arg;
p.Start();
```

Problem is, it appears that `MyProcess.exe` is being denied rights to write to the log file, even though `localhost\administrator` unquestionably has rights to the log folder.  If I run `MyProcess.exe` from a command line, it works perfectly.

So, is it possible that the process is being executed using a different user login?

Can you think of any other reason why `MyProcess.exe` is being denied rights to write the log file?

**UPDATE:** the log file is being written to the local machine, but using a network address, i.e. `\\MyPC\LogFolder`.  When I change the code to refer to `C:\MyFolder`, everything works fine.  It's obviously having a problem with the network address (even though it's local).

What sharing settings do I need to put on the folder so that the local system account can access the file?

Comment: Any reason you don't just make the service run as LocalSystem?

Comment: @KingCronus - not really, we were kind of thrashing for a reason why the process wasn't writing.  Apparently LocalSystem doesn't have rights to the log folder.  What's the formal account name of LocalSystem, so I can give that account rights on the shared folder?

Comment: Seems very odd, LocalSystem should have Admin access to most places? Where are you putting your log file?

Comment: @Shaul you can create a user that got the required rights (read/write the log) and assign it to the service in services.msc using the Log On As setting. http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sys_srv_logon_user.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: @KingCronus - the log file is going to a local folder, but it's being addressed as a network share i.e. `\\mycomputer\logfolder'.  The log folder is shared with full access rights granted to `Everyone`, and `Adminstrator`, and the `Administrators` group is the Owner.  Overkill, but I'm getting desperate!  ;-)

Comment: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2004/10/28/createprocessasuser.aspx This one has it pretty nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked it out.

The problem, as noted in my update, is that the process was addressing the log folder using a network share address, `\\MyPC\LogFolder`, and when we switched the configuration so that it wrote instead to `c:\Logfolder`, it worked fine.

So it seems that when you address a local folder, the `localhost\Administrator` account is deemed to have sufficient rights.  But when you go via the network share, you need to present valid network credentials, and `localhost\Administrator` just doesn't cut it.  If you change to use `MYDOMAIN\MyUser`, it works even using the network share address.

Comment: @KingCronus - thanks for your help - you got me thinking in the right direction!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using impersonating, than it impersonates a user that can be the currrent or a specified user. if not it will run under the Local System, with the privileges of the local system.

Comment: How do you use impersonation to run as the same user that's running the current process?

Answer (score 1):

```
p.StartInfo.Domain = "UserName";
p.StartInfo.Password = "Passw0rd!";
```

You can get the username from:

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name
```

Comment: It's a windows service - no UI allowed.  I need to run the 2nd process with the same credentials as the user running the windows service.

Comment: @Shaul Try, instead, doing `p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;`. This might make it run with the same user credentials.